# How to configure UIButton to use showsTouchWhenHighlighted?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I have a UIButton that's 90x90 in size and I would like it to glow when tapped.  Using showsTouchWhenHighlighted will make it glow but it's glowing out of the center of the button and for a small radius only.  This might work well for a small button like the info button, but for my button size, it's not.  Is there anything I can do to make it glow from the outer perimeter of the button before I resort to designing a highlighted state?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to do what you want:

1. Use different highlighted background image for your button's highlighted state,
2. Use CoreGraphics to draw the glow effect in your button's `IBAction` (`touchDown` is a decent place).

This is assuming you want some kind of custom glow effect of course - UIButtons already naturally have a highlighted effect when touched.